# Is there a template for build a roslyn analyzer with new msbuild SDK csproj?

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, roslyn-code-analysis

I have the analyzer being built with

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <PackageId>Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn</PackageId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="2.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Weingartner.Json.Migration.Common_\Weingartner.Json.Migration.Common.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

but I need to put it in a nuget package in the analyzer format. What are the msbuild tags and content to pack the nuget package correctly. For some context I will use the following powershell script to build the nuget package

```
$version=gitversion /output json /showvariable FullSemVer
dotnet pack -o ./artifacts  --configuration Release /p:Version=$version Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn\Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.csproj
dotnet nuget push Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn\artifacts\Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.$version.nupkg
```

The open source project this question applies to is

https://github.com/Weingartner/Migrations.Json.Net

Answer (score 0):

There's some documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/analyzers-conventions

And an example here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/tree/master/nuget/Roslyn.Diagnostics.Analyzers

Since you're talking about new SDK proj, I assume you are targetting mainly package reference projects and since install.ps1/uninstall.ps1 is not compatible with Package Reference, I'd suggest not relying on those scripts. Ideally you don't have them in your package.

Comment: When you follow the breadcrumbs it seems you end up with a large *.csx (csharp script) that bootstraps the nuspec file. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/master/build/GenerateAnalyzerNuspec.csx